# TortoiseCVS icon overlays broken

Tags: cvs, windows-shell, tortoisecvs

My Tortoise CVS controlled software's version is up-to-date with the server. However, the top level folder icon always has a red X

[image]

All the files and folders inside this one have green checks

[image]

I have tried resolving conflicts (There are no conflicts to resolve) and refreshing folder status (nothing seems to happen)

[image]

Any ideas of why the icon shows the red X? I'm wondering if there's really something wrong (and how to determine that) or if it's just a cosmetic bug.

Comment: Have you got any files you've deleted but haven't committed?

Comment: @ChrisW When I commit, there's nothing in the list. Wouldn't they would come back when I update if that were the case?

Comment: Yeh - it should be in the commit list if there was anything. I only suggested it as it's the thing I normally forget about!

Comment: You could try deleting your local copy and doing a fresh checkout.